# How can I quickly add entries from one data-frame into another using R?

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a dataset of species and dietary information (in proportion to 100%).

My data currently looks like this:

```
df_1<- data.frame(species=c("Species A","Species A","Species A","Species B","Species B","Species B"),
food_categories=c("food category 1","food category 2","food category 3","food category 1","food category 2","food category 3"),values=c(0.1,0.2,0.7,0.7,0.2,0.1))
df_1

 first_column   second_column third_column
1    Species A food category 1          0.1
2    Species A food category 2          0.2
3    Species A food category 3          0.7
4    Species B food category 1          0.7
5    Species B food category 2          0.2
6    Species B food category 3          0.1
```

And I want to quickly turn it into something like this:

```
df_2<-data.frame(Species=c("Species A","Species B"),food_category_1=c(0.1,0.7),food_category_2=c(0.2,0.2),food_category_3=c(0.7,0.1))
df_2

Species food_category_1 food_category_2 food_category_3
1 Species A             0.1             0.2             0.7
2 Species B             0.7             0.2             0.1
```

I have many species in the dataset and I'm trying to figure out how to do this automatically.

I tried to use the transpose() function, but it's not quite what I need since I need to reduce the number of would-be columns.

Comment: Among the most popular options would be via tidyr: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df_1, names_from = food_categories, values_from = values)` - you can find more base R and other package options here: [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)